# Find a prime $P$ such that a given ideal is $P$-primary

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals

According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834852/when-a-monomial-ideal-is-primary) question (or rather answer),  a monomial ideal of a polynomial ring is primary iff every variable appearing in it has some power in $I$.

So for example the ideals $(y),(x^3,y^4)$ of $k[x,y]$ are ($P_i$-)primary for some prime ideals $P_i$.

That is, $Ass(k[x,y]/(y))=\{P_1\}$ and $Ass(k[x,y]/(x^3,y^4))=\{P_2\}$.

I looks clear for me that $(y)=Ann_{k[x,y]/(y)}(1)$. So $P_1=(y)$.

But how to find $P_2$? Is it $(x,y)$? If so, how to find an element of the quotient whose annihilator equals $(x,y)$? Is there a general procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P_2$ must be the radical of $(x^3, y^4)$, so $P_2 = (x,y)$.  The annihilator of $x^2 y^3$ in the quotient $k[x,y]/(x^3,y^4)$ is $(x,y)$. You should be able to generalize this.

Comment: Probably I don't know enough theory; is it always the case that an ideal $I$ from a primary decomposition is $rad(I)$-primary?

Comment: Yes, if $I$ is a *primary* ideal, then it is always $rad(I)$-primary.